# Handle jquery event of one page to another page

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am using jquery to opening a lightbox.I am using two pages for it(Because my requirement is
to fetch the lightbox content from another page).Here is my code for fisr page on which i have written the code for opening the lightbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#open').click(function(){
    $("#light").load("light.html");
        $('div.white_content').css("display","block");

    });
    $('#close').click(function(){
        $('div.white_content').css("display","none");
    });
});
</script>

<style>
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid orange;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" id="open">here</a></p>
    <div id="light" class="white_content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is My Code Where the content for lightbox is

the page in light.html

```
<div>Hello this is sandeep<br />
        Widevision technology
 <br />indore <a href = "javascript:void(0)" id="close">Close</a>
</div>
```

The above code is Working fine though.The problem is in closing the lightbox.Since i have fetch the lightbox content from another page(light.html).My close event code is  as you can see above  written on index.html

```
$('#close').click(function(){
        $('div.white_content').css("display","none");
    });
```

The above code is not working but if i move above code to light.html ,it will work.But i want to make it work from index.html.AS the open event is working from this page why not close event?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `.click(function() {` into `.live('click', function() {`

see [jquery live api doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: alternatively you could also try to bind the click event after the lightbox has been loaded (probably in the callback of your ajax call), but live should generally do the trick

Comment: sidenote: be aware not to bind the click event a second time on the already existing `a#close`